# Forms : How to add elements on the client without a (ajax) round trip to the server

Tags: forms, ajax, javascript

I have been playing with AJAX examples.

What I'd like to do is have elements added to the form without requiring a round trip to the server. I guess Drupal requires this to rebuild the form with the new elements. Is it possible to do this without calling back Drupal?

Comment: 10 years later somebody decides to close a question (that probably doesn’t apply anymore since Drupal) lol

Answer (score 1):

Short of building your form with a huge amount of fields, hiding them, and then showing them dependent on the user's action, no you can't.

Comment: Thanks for confirming !
I finally made a custom widget, a hidden field (model) and used jquery to manage the view (add more fields etc.) and on the server it unserializes json from the hidden field to get the data  (but it does not degrade to no-js :/ )